# What's the best way to display a list sectioned by a properly on the list item?

Tags: swiftui

I have a swiftUI list displaying a list of players.
I want to group the list in sections based on the player's team where "team" is a separate type.
On tapping one of the players an edit view opens allowing modifying the player's team.
On edit view save and dismiss i want the master list to move the player from the privous team section to the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this functionality by using the List view in SwiftUI along with the ForEach view to iterate over the array of players and display them in separate sections based on their team. You can also use the NavigationLink view to display an edit view when a player is tapped, and then use a closure to update the list when the player's team is edited and saved.

Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates how to implement this functionality:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Player: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var team: String
}

struct PlayerView: View {
    @State var players: [Player] = [
        Player(name: "Huy", team: "Team A"),
        Player(name: "Bao", team: "Team A"),
        Player(name: "Hieu", team: "Team B"),
        Player(name: "Luu", team: "Team C"),
        Player(name: "Tuy", team: "Team C")
    ]
    
    var teams: [String] {
        return Array(Set(players.map { $0.team }))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(teams, id: \.self) { team in
                    Section(header: Text(team)) {
                        ForEach(players.filter { $0.team == team }) { player in
                            NavigationLink(destination: EditView(editedPlayer: player,
                                                                 onSave: { editedPlayer in
                                if let index = players.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == editedPlayer.id }) {
                                    players[index] = editedPlayer
                                }
                            })) {
                                Text(player.name)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("Players")
        }
    }
}

struct PlayerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PlayerView()
    }
}

struct EditView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State var editedPlayer: Player
    
    let onSave: (Player) -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Team")) {
                TextField("Team", text: $editedPlayer.team)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Edit Player")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Save") {
            onSave(editedPlayer)
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        })
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]